# How to prevent layout shift when using CSS grid's auto-fill/auto-fit feature?

Tags: css, css-grid

I created a layout with grid that wraps columns when the screen get smaller, thanks to the `auto-fill` feature:

**css**

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(2rem, 32rem));
```

However, the code above causes an unpleasant layout shift on page load:

[image: GIF showing the layout shift]

I changed my code to the following to fix the problem:

**css**

```
grid-template-columns: minmax(6rem, 32rem) minmax(6rem, 32rem);
@media only screen and (max-width :768px) {
    grid-template-columns: minmax(6rem, 32rem);
}
```

It works fine, but I'd rather not use media queries.

Are there techniques to use `auto-fill` and avoid shifting the layout on page load?

Comment: Media queries are part and parcel of web design and **not** using them makes little sense. Most layout methods including css-grid **require** them to fulfil their functions.

Comment: I don't understand how that shift is even happening, regardless of content load time `auto-fill` will generate columns depending on how many children at `max size` if it can fit in all columns.  If say you're on a wide screen the columns will set next to each from the beginning, And If on a smaller screen they will stack. You will only see a shifting issue if you resize the window, which is not a problem because you're looking for it.

Comment: Are you using autofill or autofit? It shouldn't happen with auto-fill. Refer to this excellent guide for the difference between the two. https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/